# Prevent ajax calls from spammers

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Is there a way to prevent a ajax call being called multiple times?. I am working with C# Asp.net, and I use `webmethods` which are used by ajax calls, and I am afraid spammers make multiple calls to the methods.

Comment: have you ever seen those messages that asks you to type what is in the image?, that can help

Comment: use a webservice that requires SessionState with a valid authentication token.